# Align div vertically with compressed paragraph (cannot use flex)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, wkhtmltopdf

I know how to align divs, but I am using wkhtmltopdf, which does not support display flex. 
I have wrote a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x15a6u8z/) code with an example of my problem.
Here is the explanation: I have three divs with two paragraphs inside. The third paragraph should be compressed to a fixed height (here I put 3cm). When I do this, I cannot have my divs aligned as you can see in the fiddle example. You will notice that if I remove this constraint (the width:3cm), the three divs align perfectly. 
What should I do to have them all aligned even though I have the constraint?

Here is the code:

```css
.box {
  width: 15cm;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.compressed_paragraph {
  width: 3cm;
}

.set_height {
  height: 2cm;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="ib box1">
    <div class="set_height">
      <p>First text</p>
      <p>Some text underneath</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ib box2">
    <div class="set_height">
      <p>Second text</p>
      <p>Some text underneath</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ib box3">
    <div class="set_height">
      <p class="compressed_paragraph">Should compress the thrird text</p>
      <p>Some text underneath</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can realign the divs by using [`vertical-align: bottom;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) in the `.ib` class:

```
.ib {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Note:** most alignment would work as well, since the divs have the same height.

```css
.box {
  width: 15cm;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.compressed_paragraph {
  width: 3cm;
}

.set_height {
  height: 2cm;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="ib box1">
    <div class="set_height">
      <p>First text</p>
      <p>Some text underneath</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ib box2">
    <div class="set_height">
      <p>Second text</p>
      <p>Some text underneath</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ib box3">
    <div class="set_height">
      <p class="compressed_paragraph">Should compress the thrird text</p>
      <p>Some text underneath</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```